# Semantic UI Dropdown component max-width in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dropdown

I can't figure out how to set the max-width of the `Dropdown` component in ReactJS. I tried with

```
.Menu Dropdown {
    max-width: 5rem !important;
}
```

With no luck. They use way too much space for the text they are showing. Can someone explain me how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: use % style={{width: '100%'}} or max-width: 100%; and adjust accordingly

Comment: Inspect the CSS classes of the rendered HTML. Target those CSS class name(s) instead of the name of the component.

Comment: Looking only at your CSS is a bit hard to solve your problem but at a glance I'd say that Dropdown is probably a class and you are missing the dot in front of it. .Menu .Dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `fluid` prop to the `Dropdown` component should do the job according to the semantic react docs [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/).

Example:

```
<Dropdown fluid> ... </Dropdown>
```

Hope this helps.